# rust macros: ident and ty are conflicting with each other

Tags: rust

```rust
macro_rules! thisis {
    ($t: ty) => {
        println!("this is a type")
    };
    ($t: ident) => {
        println!("this is an ident")
    };
}

fn main()
{
    const variable: i32 = 32;
    thisis!(i32);
    thisis!(variable);
}
```

in the example above it prints "this is a type", in both cases, it doesn't really recognize the difference between types and idents. it goes with which ever difinition comes first.

Answer (score 3):

Macros are not context sensitive. Your macro doesn't know whether a given name is a variable or a type in the current scope. It only knows what it can glean from the context-free syntax of the language, and by those rules both `i32` and `variable` are valid type and/or identifier names.

Specifically, the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#metavariables) defines `ty` and `ident` as follows.

> - `ty`: a [*Type*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html#type-expressions)
> - `ident`: an [IDENTIFIER_OR_KEYWORD](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html) or [RAW_IDENTIFIER](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html)

Where *Type* is defined as several things, but one of those is [TypePath](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#paths-in-types), which is effectively any string of identifiers connected by `::`.

IDENTIFIER_OR_KEYWORD, as the name implies, is any valid identifier name in Rust, or a Rust keyword. RAW_IDENTIFIER is an identifier (including a keyword) prefixed with `r#` (this allows us to, for instance, use the word `if` as a variable name by writing it as `r#if`

So ordinary identifiers like `foo` are both `ty` and `ident` by Rust's syntax rules. Qualified names like `foo::bar` are *only* `ty` and not `ident`. Meanwhile, a language keyword like `while` or `if` (written *without* the raw identifier `r#` prefix) would be an `ident` but not a `ty`.

You just don't have this level of semantic information at the macro level, unfortunately.

Comment: so what do you suggest to make the example work as expected without using the RAW_IDENTIFIER ?

Comment: In the abstract, you can't distinguish. Depending on what you actually plan to do with this macro in your real use case, there may be something that can be done. Could you explain a bit more of your actual use case? Because unfortunately, as the question stands right now, the asnwer is "it can't be done".

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is to create sizeof macro similar to the one in C: `use std::mem; 
macro_rules! sizeof {
 ($t: ty) => (mem::size_of::<$t>());
 ($var: ident,) => (mem::size_of_val(&$var));
}`

Comment: @Nour-eddineTaleb You cannot do that. There is a reason they are different functions. If you want, you can try to differentiate via the case (only with a proc macro), but of course this can fail.